# Service Worker: How to build "Fresh" version of website for each new deployment?

Tags: polymer, service-worker, firebase-polymer, polymer-cli, sw-precache

## The Problem

I'm having an issue with a website (built w/ the [Polymer Shop](https://github.com/Polymer/shop) template) in production that's serving up old versions of code despite my new and improved deployments.

I'm using the Polymer CLI `$ polymer build` command along w/ the Firebase Tools `$ firebase deploy` command to push up changes to Firebase Hosting. After deploy is complete, I navigate to the website only to see the changes not updating:

- **Chrome:** I see the old version of the website first and have to "hard refresh" for the changes to appear.
- **FireFox:** I see the old version of the website first and have to "hard refresh" for the changes to appear.

---

> Here's the before n' after shot:

[image]

---

## Service Worker workflow?

I'm trying to figure out what the best workflow is for this. I want to set things up so that every time I make a new deploy, the entire site is wiped clean and the service worker resets itself through the inter webs and I'll be 100% sure that existing users will get that newly deployed experience

> with out having to *hard refresh* or use *incognito mode*.

---

### Should I...

- Delete the service worker and deploy the new version without it (bad idea) ?
- Create a "New Project" in the Firebase Console and re-link the custom domain up (tedious) ?
- Find the "magic button" to press inside Firebase Console to reset (does this exist) ?
- Edit the `sw-precache-config.js` file (not sure how) ?
- Handle this in the `$ polymer build` to configure the `sw-precache` (not sure how) ?
- Something awesome that  don't even know about  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` ?

---

I know that the *problem* exists inside the `sw-precache-config.js` file, but I'm unsure if this is where I should be *fixing* this.

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    '/index.html',
    '/manifest.json',
    '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js',
    '/images/*'
  ],
  navigateFallback: '/index.html',
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!.*\.html$|\/data\/).*/],
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /\/data\/images\/.*/,
      handler: 'cacheFirst',
      options: {
        cache: {
          maxEntries: 200,
          name: 'items-cache'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /\/data\/.*json/,
      handler: 'fastest',
      options: {
        cache: {
          maxEntries: 100,
          name: 'data-cache'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

---

The Service Worker is an amazing tool and I definitely want it in my projects. I just need to learn how to tame the beast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about polymer, but this is the flow I usually do with service workers.
- In the client I check if there is a update, the app notify the user if he/she wants to update.
- User accepts new version, then client send a message to sw to **skipWating**.
**client.js:**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js').then(function(reg) {
    reg.addEventListener('updatefound', function() {

      reg.installing.addEventListener('statechange', function() {

        if (reg.installing.state == 'installed') {
          // Notify the user, there is a app new version.
          // User accept
           reg.installing.postMessage({msg: 'skipwaiting'});
        }
      });
    });
});
```

-In the service worker listen for the **message** and skipWating if user accepts the new version.
**serviceWorker.js:**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data.msg === 'skipwaiting') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

The client refresh the application after the service worker has change state.
**client.js:**

```
let refreshing;

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function() {
    if (refreshing) 
    return;
    window.location.reload();
    refreshing = true;
});
```

Maybe this can give you an idea.

Comment: I ended up setting both the handlers: "networkFirst" and it fixed the issue. This was my plan all along.., but I wanted to ask a few questions before I started turning knobs